# Error "syntax error, unexpected +" in i++ CPLEX

Tags: cplex

I write this on CPLEX:

```
{
    for (j==2) {

        for (i=1; i<=6; i++) {
    
            y[i][j][15] == 1 && y[i][j][16] == 0 || y[i][j][15] == 0 && y[i][j][16] == 1;
        
        }   
    }
}
```

but Cplex give me error in i++ and and in the parentheses that I have highlighted. where am I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dvar boolean y[1..6][1..6][15..16];

subject to
{

forall (j in 2..2) {

        forall(i in 1..6) {
    
            y[i][j][15] == 1 && y[i][j][16] == 0 || y[i][j][15] == 0 && y[i][j][16] == 1;
        
        }   
    }
    
  }
```

works fine